# how to filter records with latest date

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

im trying to filter my database records with columns **SearchCode** and **CreateDate** which should give me a single record whos searchcode is the latest date. I am using bunifuTextBox5.Text to filter the **SearchCode**. The code works well to filter the SearchCode but when I included the datetime part it no longer shows records on grid. the `x.CreateDate == DateTime.MaxValue` is not working

```
 try
        {

         
            db = new MedriveEntities();
           _PrePOrderList = db.SOrderTables.Where(x => x.SearchCode.StartsWith(bunifuTextBox5.Text) && x.CreateDate == DateTime.MaxValue).ToList();

           


            if (_PrePOrderList != null)
            {


                List<Supplier> oSuppliers = db.Suppliers.ToList();

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataRow dr = null;
                dt.Columns.Add("SOrderID");
                dt.Columns.Add("CreateDate");
                dt.Columns.Add("GrandTotal");
                dt.Columns.Add("InvoiceNo");

         


                foreach (SOrderTable oPOredr in _PrePOrderList)
                {
                    dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["SOrderID"] = oPOredr.QSOrdersID;
                    dr["CreateDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(oPOredr.CreateDate).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
                    dr["GrandTotal"] = oPOredr.GrandTotal;
                    dr["InvoiceNo"] = oPOredr.InvoiceNo;
            
                   


                    // item.Tag = oPOredr;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                gridControl2.DataSource = dt;


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

this code is not showing the max (**CreateDate**) Please I need help I'm still new in c#

Comment: `DateTime.MaxValue` will give you the following date: `31.12.9999 23:59:59`. Basically you are searching for values from a very distant future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple sort it by date and take first one

```
order = db.SOrderTables.Where(x => x.SearchCode.StartsWith(bunifuTextBox5.Text)).OrderByDescending(x=>x.CreateDate).Take(1);
```